# How to modify ajax response before jsTree creation?

Tags: jstree

How can I modify ajax response before jsTree creation? I would like to access each node ID and add prefix to it. On jsTree page the only clue is this: the function will receive two arguments - the node being loaded & a function". I need to do that before the tree is actually created, to avoid duplicate ID in the document.

```
"json_data" : {
"ajax" : { 
  "type": "GET", 
  "url" : "tree.json" 
 }, 
"data" : function(node, func){
        //how to use that? 
}}
```

I have expected to get JSON data here, modify it and return? But this will explode.

Comment: I have found a comment in jsTree code: "accepts two arguments - node being loaded and a callback to pass the result to, will be executed in the current tree's scope & ajax won't be supported". Why?? When i comment out ajax settings, this function gets arguments, node and call back function, but I need to modify AJAX data - should this be done in "on success" callback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have successfully manipulated data using the success callback in the instantiation of the jsTree.  In my case, I am parsing XML data returned as JSON from a .NET webmethod.  It should work for your case in a similar manner.

```
"ajax": {
  "type": "GET"
  "url": "tree.json",
  "success": function (x) {
    //manipulate string x to change id's here
    return x;
  }, ...
```

Another method is to use the "complete" callback function to manipulate the jsTree in its final form.  I don't recommend it in your case of duplicate id's, however.